# Why can't I create a new table in my existing database using EF Core? (Code First)

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration

I want to know why I cant add a new table into my existing database.
I've created a new model:

```
public class RegisterAccount
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Added the necessary Dbset

```
public DbSet<RegisterAccount> RegisterAccount {get; set;}
```

I've typed in the PMC:
Add-Migration, then Update-Database but I can't see the new table in the database?
I've restarted SSMS and refreshed everything, am i missing something?

Comment: What is your connection string, and are you looking in the right place?

Comment: Where have you added your dbset? In which file?

Comment: My connection string is located in the appsettings.json file. Initially I done a database first, but now seeming as the code first is alot easier, I want to do it this way instead.

Comment: With regards to my dbset location, I have placed them in the context where the other dbsets are placed as well. 

Example: 

```
public DbSet<Login> Login {get; set;}
public DbSet<RegisterAccount> RegisterAccount {get; set;}
public DbSet<ServerList> ServerList {get; set;}
```

Hope that clears it for you

Comment: The second command should be Update-Database and Not Update-Migration.

Comment: Obligatory remark:  a 'real program' should not store literal Passwords. Make sure you know about Hashing.

Comment: Oh yes! I defo meant to type Update-Database, sorry for the confusion

Comment: You can edit the auto generated Migration class. Or, show that,we fix it.